# How to make the text bold between HTML tags?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have text similar to this:

```html
(27)Some normal text\<b\>, and some bold text\</b\>, in a paragraph\<b\>.\</b\>.
```

I tried the following code. It makes the text bold, but it does not remove the HTML tags, and part of the text is removed as well:

```
Sub BoldTags()
Dim X As Long, BoldOn As Boolean
BoldOn = False 'Default from start of cell is not to bold
For X = 1 To Len(ActiveCell.Text)
    If UCase(Mid(ActiveCell.Text, X, 3)) = "<b>" Then
        BoldOn = True
        ActiveCell.Characters(X, 3).Delete
    End If
    If UCase(Mid(ActiveCell.Text, X, 4)) = "</b>" Then
        BoldOn = False
        ActiveCell.Characters(X, 4).Delete
    End If
    ActiveCell.Characters(X, 1).Font.Bold = BoldOn
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**As a jump-start to understanding your problem**

In order to successfully make the text between the HTML tags bold, it is necessary to set correct start and end tags `<b> ... </b>`  *(or also to identify - in this case meaningless - `<b/>` tags which would be start and end tag in one without any text between)*. Furthermore, `</b\>` or `<b\>` or `</b\>` are not regular tags and will not be reliably recognized by your code, so pairwise character formatting results in a total mess here.

If your post is not just about typos, I would recommend eliminating or otherwise neutralizing such incorrect entries e.g. with `Replace`, but in any case validate the correct change from `<b>` to `</b>` tags in advance. - Feel free to try step-by-step using the above explanation, explore some html basics and only post a new question if you encounter a concrete, reproducible problem with your own now improved code.